# How to add image from drawable to ListView populate from database

Tags: android, image, listview, drawable, simplecursoradapter

I'm wondering how to add images from drawables to my listview. I have ListView with two TextViews(id, activity) that i retrieve from database. Could You give me some advice?:)

I'm taking data with

```
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.history_list_item, cursor, new String[] { Tracks._ID,
                    Tracks.ACTIVITY }, new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.activity });
```

I want to display image next to textview that depend on activity value.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

you need to write your own adapter which extends SimpleCursorAdapter and then override getView method to set images for your textview as coumpund-drawable.

Following is just an example, but you can use it in your own way:

```
private class NotesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note>{
        public NotesListAdapter() {
            super(getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_note_row, R.id.noteHead, notes);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_note_row, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtHeading = ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.noteHead));
                holder.txtContent = ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.noteBody));
                holder.image = ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.note_icon));

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            //set texts
            holder.txtHeading.setText("bla bla");
            holder.txtHeading.setCompoundDrawables(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_icon), null, null, null);
            holder.txtContent.setText("bla bla");

            return convertView;
        }
}

//this is better approach as suggested by Google-IO for ListView
    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView txtHeading;
        TextView txtContent;
        ImageView image;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for quick answer, i will use it:)

Comment: @user1199476 if u got the right answer just tick it.Its gives reference for future use.

Answer (score 2):

If I properly understood your question, one solution would be to include an ImageView in your layout, like this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.history_list_item, cursor, new String[] { Tracks.SYMBOL,
                Tracks._ID, Tracks.ACTIVITY },
                new int[] { R.id.symbol, R.id.id, R.id.activity });
```

In the code above, Tracks.SYMBOL is the table column with the resource identification and R.id.symbol is the id of your ImageView. Then you would have to implement the SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder interface and set your implementation into the cursor adapter.

Before we see an example, there is one consideration to be made: The cursor column Tracks.SYMBOL could have integers with values which are equal to the desired resource fields in the R.drawable class. This is not convenient since those fields are generated automatically, thus not giving us control over their values. One solution would be to store a String with the class field name and use reflection to get the field values.

Here is an example of a ViewBinder being attached to the previously defined adapter:

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        boolean binded = false;
        if (view instanceof ImageView) {
            int resourceId R.drawable.default_img;
            String image = cursor.getString(columnIndex).trim();
            try {
                resourceId = R.drawable.class.getField(image).getInt(null);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            }
            ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(resourceId);
            binded = true;
        }
        return binded;
    }
});
```

One point with the setViewValue method is that if it returns false, then SimpleCursorAdapter will perform the binding in the way it normally does. But if that method returns true, SimpleCursorAdapter considers the job done and do not try to bind that field anymore.

I'm just starting with Android programming. I did something like that in one project and it worked fine. I don't know if there is an easier way.

Best regards.